# LibGDX/Socket.io: No OpenGL context found in the current thread

Tags: android, node.js, opengl-es, socket.io, libgdx

I code a multiplayer game with LibGDX using Node.js and specifically Socket.io.
When a new player connects, the client gets an event called getPlayers:

```
public void configSocketEvents(){
socket.on("getPlayers", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            JSONArray objects = (JSONArray) args[0];
            try {
                for(int i = 0; i < objects.length(); i++){

                    Player enemy = new Player();
                   //...
```

Player class:

```
public Player() {
    renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    init();
}
```

Now when a second client connects, the following error is outputted for both clients:

```
Exception in thread "EventThread" java.lang.RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
...
at de.ej.facharbeitsspiel.Game.Player.<init>(Player.java:26)
at de.ej.facharbeitsspiel.Screens.GameScreenMP$1.call(GameScreenMP.java:149)
```

Line 149 is the line `Player enemy = new Player();`, so there is obviously the problem that a new `ShapeRenderer()` can't be loaded because it's not the OpenGL render thread.

Any idea how to fix this problem? Thank you in advance

Comment: Sure, don't create things in another thread that need to be created in the render thread. You might want to read up into: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns. Your Player class (game logic) should not care about ShapeRenderer (render logic). Anyways, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, because your question is too broad (doesnt contain enough details) to answer.

Comment: But if I create a Player outside of the Socket Event, everything works fine. Which pieces of information are missing in my question?

Comment: If you really want to take that approach (which isn't recommendable) then this will help you include the required information: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. In general though, if you want to do something on the render thread then use `Gdx.app.postRunnable`.

Comment: Okay, I solved the problem. As you recommended, I did not create a new ShapeRenderer in the Player class but I created one in my WorldRenderer class and used this one. So thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved the problem.

As Xoppa recommended in the comment section under the question, it's a bad idea to create the ShapeRenderer in the player class, so I created one in my WorldRenderer class and used this one.